# EidUnknownProtocal Error using TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, paypal-rest-sdk

I am getting an EidUnknownProtocal Error when using TIdHTTP Get method for using a Paypal Rest API.

Here is my code thus far:

```
PROCEDURE ApprovePaymentCall ;
Var
 HTTP :TIdHTTP ;
 SSLHandler :TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL ;
 ApprovePaymentObj :TJSONObject ;
 InputJSON, OutputResponse: TStringStream ;
 ResponseStr :String ;

BEGIN
  HTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil) ;
  SSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil) ; //Opens SSL Connection
  HTTP.IOHandler := SSLHandler ; //set HTTP IOHandler to SSL Connection

  With HTTP Do
      BEGIN
        Request.BasicAuthentication := False ;
        Request.CustomHeaders.Values['authorization'] := Format(TokenResponse.TokenType + ' %s', [TokenResponse.TokenValue]) ;
        Request.ContentType := 'application/json' ;
        HandleRedirects := True ;
        AllowCookies := True ;
        Request.Pragma :=  'no-cache ';
        Request.CacheControl :=  'no-cache ';
        Request.Connection :=  'close ';
      END ; {With HTTP}

  try
    ApprovePaymentObj := TJSONObject.Create ;
    InputJSON := TStringStream.Create(ApprovePaymentObj.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8) ;
    OutputResponse := TStringStream.Create ;
    HTTP.Get(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5M791976LA430740H, OutputResponse) ;

    ApprovePaymentObj := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OutputResponse.DataString),0) as TJSONObject;
    ResponseStr := OutputResponse.DataString
  finally
    ApprovePaymentObj.Free ;
    InputJSON.Free ;
    OutputResponse.Free ;
  end ; {try-finally}

  HTTP.Free ;
  SSLHandler.Free ;
END ; {ApprovePaymentCall}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is not a copy/paste of your real code, as `HTTP.Get(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-5M791976LA430740H, OutputResponse) ;` does not compile since the first parameter is missing quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The ONLY time that `TIdHTTP` raises an `EIdUnknownProtocol` exception is inside of `TIdCustomHTTP.PrepareRequest()` when it is trying to figure out what port to connect to.  If `TIdHTTP.Request.URL` (which `TIdHTTP.Get()` populates before calling `PrepareRequest()`) does not contain an explicit port number, and does not specify an `http` or `https` URL, and `TIdHTTP.URL.Port` does not contain a port number from an earlier request, then `EIdUnknownProtocol` is raised.

Given the code you have shown (which does not compile, BTW), the URL you are passing to `TIdHTTP.Get()` satisfies the `https` URL requirement, so `TIdHTTP` should be connected to the default HTTPS port.  Without a complete stack trace leading up to the error, or a log of the actual HTTP requests/responses, I can only assume that the server is redirecting `TIdHTTP` to a new URL that is somehow malforming `TIdHTTP`'s internal URL on the next request after the redirect.

Comment: Remy, I copied the response from the PaymentRequest into notepad and pasted the Links Object Array in my code. From your response, am I supposed to provide a port number or is there something else I am missing? Is there a default Port number that should be used for Paypal Rest API?

Comment: Unless PayPal documents a different port, the default HTTPS port should suffice. Something else is going on that you have not shown yet.  Where is `TokenResponse` coming from? Have you even tried stepping through `TIdHTTP`'s source code with the debugger yet? What does the call stack look like when `EIdUnknownProtocol` is raised?

Comment: I got it to work. the url had a leading space and once I used the TrimLeft command, I no longer get the error. But I am not getting the results I expected. I was supposed to get the users Payer-ID but instead I get the code of the webpage in the HTTP.GET response string. I wanted to send a screen shot of the result I am getting, but not sure how to do that here

Comment: If you actually read PayPal's [documentation for Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/), it says that once you have obtained a token, navigating to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=<tokenValue>` redirects to an HTML login page for the user to fill in their PayPal credentials. That is the webpage you are seeing `TIdHTTP.Get()` return...

Comment: After the user logs in, they see a transaction review page.  These pages need to be displayed to the user in a web browser (or else you have to parse the HTML and display the relevant fields in your own GUI).  When the user accepts or rejects the transaction, the browser is then redirected to the URL you provided to `SetExpressCheckout`, and then your code can finish the check-out as needed.  If you want to handle the login and review inside your app, you are going to have to do some extra HTML parsing inside your app and perform the necessary HTTP requests to submit the relevant HTML forms.

Comment: Yes I have manged to figure the first part of your comments. Would a shellExecute method work or do I need to do something else? I think a more elegant approach is to handle the login and review inside my app even if it means a little extra work. Can u please point me in the right direction regarding shellexecute and handling login and review of information from my application?  Thank you